# How many "temperatures" are there for a Rx Observable?

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive

All over the Rx.Net literature there are references to what is commonly know as the **temperature** of an observable.

There are **cold observables** (like the ones created by `Observable.Interval()` and similar factory methods), which will create side effects every time that a new Subscription is created.

On the other side of the spectrum there are **hot observables** (like `Subject<T>`) which will onboard new subscriptions as they come.

There are also **warm observables**, like the ones returned by `RefCount()` which will execute the initialisation every time one subscription is created, but only if there was no other active subscription. The behaviour of these warm observables is explained [here](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) by Dave Sexton:

> Alternatively, you can call Publish then RefCount to get an IObservable that is shared among multiple consecutive observers.  Note that this isn't truly a hot observable - it's more like a warm observable.  RefCount makes a single subscription to the underlying observable while there's at least one observer of your query.  When your query has no more observers, changing the reference count to 0, the underlying subscription is disposed.  If another observer subscribes to your query later, moving the reference count from 0 to 1 again, then RefCount makes a new subscription to the underlying observable, causing subscription side-effects to occur again.

Are there any other temperatures that one should be aware of? Is it possible to obtain programmatically the temperature of an Observable?

Comment: Perhaps you missed my other blog post in which I dive deep into temperature: http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx

Comment: Actually I did read it, but only after posting the question. Great job ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy question first:

> Is it possible to obtain programmatically the temperature of an Observable?

No. Best you can do is subscribe and see what happens.

The observable 'contract' specifies that when you subscribe to an observable you get zero or more OnNext messages, optionally followed by either one OnCompleted or one OnError message. The contract doesn't specify anything about how multiple or earlier/later subscribers are treated, which is what observable 'temperature' is mostly concerned with.

> Are there any other temperatures that one should be aware of?

I wouldn't even think of it in such concrete or discrete terms as you have specified.

I think of it in terms of on-subscribe effects: The coldest of observables have all their effects happen on subscribe (like `Observable.Return(42)`). The hottest of observables have no effects happening on subscribe (`new Subject<int>()`). In between those two poles is a continuum.

`Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))` for example will emit a new number every 100 milliseconds. That example, unlike `Observable.Return(42)`, could be mostly 'warmed-over' via `.Publish().RefCount()`: The first subscriber starts the numbers, but the second subscriber will see the only the latest numbers, not starting from 0. However, if instead of `.Publish()` you did `.Replay(2).RefCount()`, then you have some on-subscribe effects going on. Do the `Publish` and `Replay` observables have the same 'temperature'?

TL;DR: Don't focus on the classifications that much. Understand the difference between the two and know that some observables have colder properties and some have warmer ones.

Comment: Even though I understand what you mean, I find it hard to understand how such an important factor has been left out of the types (the difference between a hot and a cold observable is only clear to the provider of the observable and completely opaque to the observer..).

Comment: I hear you. It's probably the biggest source of confusion around observables. The early documentation went out of its way to explain it, so they were certainly aware of the possible confusion. None of the ports (that I'm aware of) have done anything about it either, so I'm not sure if there's really room for an improvement.